# Background image doesn't cover entire screen

Tags: html, css, background

I have a background image of size 1620*1080, and my screen resolution is 1366*768. How is possible that it doesn't cover about 15% of my screen (the right part)?

Here's my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
body { 
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    background-image:url(background.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: red;

}
</style>
</head>
<div id="container">

</div>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I've added

```
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 100%;
```

thought maybe it would help. And `background-repeat: no-repeat;` is only there because it doesn't cover the screen.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have a div outside the body tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
body { 
    background: url(background.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

That'll give you a full-size background image whether the window is bigger or smaller than your image.

and if that doesn't work, read the rest of [this css-tricks post](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/).

Answer (score 4):

Your image ratio is `1620/1080=1.5,` and screen resolution is `1366/768=1.77`. Essentially what is happening is the image is showing up at a smaller size, while being kept to scale. The area on the right is blocked off.

Try just posting the size

```
background-size:100% 100%;
```